# How to remove None from Column containing Lists ONLY IF the List contains another string?

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I have a dataframe with a column that contains lists. These lists can contain strings, `None`, or, my personal favorite *both* i.e `['ABCD', None]`

I would really like to remove the `None` from the lists that are not empty, but keep it in the columns where the value is `[None]`. Ultimately, I will flatten these lists into strings, so in cases where the `None` is replace, the column cell will be empty which is not helpful for filtering.

I am wondering how this can be done?

Sample dataframe and sample code below:

```
data = [[1, "['ABCD', None]"], [2, "['ABCD', None]"], [3, "[None]"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item", "String1"])

df["String1"] = df["String1"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("None", ""))
```

```
   Item     String1
0   1   ['ABCD', None]
1   2   ['ABCD', None]
2   3           [None]
```

what I am getting:

```
   Item    String1
0   1     ['ABCD',]
1   2     ['ABCD',]
2   3            []
```

what I would like to see:

```
   Item    String1
0   1     ['ABCD',]
1   2     ['ABCD',]
2   3        [None]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def remove_none(x):
    if x == "[None]":
        return x
    else:
        return x.replace("None", "")
    

df["String1"].apply(remove_none)
```

---

```
0    ['ABCD', ]
1    ['ABCD', ]
2        [None]
Name: String1, dtype: object
```

Comment: The code will not change the DF. You need to use: `df["String1"] = df["String1"].apply(remove_none)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to first apply `ast.literal_eval` on the `String1` column (to convert the strings to lists) and then use list-comprehension to filter the values:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df['String1'] = df['String1'].apply(literal_eval)

df['String1'] = df['String1'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) == 1 else [v for v in x if not v is None])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Item String1
0     1  [ABCD]
1     2  [ABCD]
2     3  [None]
```